# Why is "long" interpretation of kCFPositiveInfinity different on various iDevices?

Tags: ios, 32bit-64bit, nsnumber, infinity

I have been tinkering with **NSNumber** for a little while when searching for infinity value and I have come across one interesting fact. When I do this:

```
long infinity = [((NSNumber *)kCFNumberPositiveInfinity) longValue];
```

32bit simulator interprets it as **0**, while 64bit simulator interprets it as **-9223372036854775808**.

Now I remember my Computer Architecture 101 and they used to tell us - 32bit = *smaller range*, 64bit = *wider range*. But obviously, on 64bit simulator's interpretation of positive infinity there is an overflow(since my research tells me that *positive* infinity will most likely be a *positive* number).

The question is - is this a feature(if so, then why?), or a bug?

Comment: How to you print the values respectively how do you get the values ?

Comment: I put a breakpoint under them and inspect them via lldb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the 32 bit simulator,

If you make an object from (NSNumber *)kCFNumberPositiveInfinity like this:

```
NSObject *dummy = (NSNumber *)kCFNumberPositiveInfinity;
```

and inspect it, you will see it is this:

```
dummy = (__NSCFNumber *)(double)inf
```

and when you convert it to an long value like this:

```
long longDummy = [(NSNumber *)dummy longValue];
```

it gets set to 0

if you just set a long to that value like this:

```
long testDummy = kCFNumberPositiveInfinity;
```

it gets set to 53994368

The problem (whether it be a bug, or just an unexpected implementation) is in the format of this call

```
[((NSNumber *)kCFNumberPositiveInfinity) longValue];
```

where you force it to an NSNumber, which defaults to a double, because it doesn't know better, and then get a longValue from a double.

Comment: Right, but then why does the 64bit simulator makes it such a nonsense number and not 0 as well?

Comment: interesting. So [NSNumber numberWithLong: kCFNumberPositiveInfinity] yields a different result then? (also numberWithLongLong:...?)

Comment: Those two actually produce reasonable numbers -> 26530688 on 32bit and 4322992432 on 64bit. But that's because your example is retyping kCFNumberPositiveInfinity to long, whereas I am retyping it to NSNumber.

Comment: It seems like kind of a blind retyping.  NSNumber can me one of several types of numbers.  kCFNumberPositiveInfinity seems to depend on context.  So its not too surprising that a variable input combined with a variable output produces spurious results.

Comment: I actually found a post from 2006 doing the same thing, but with int - http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2006/May/msg01766.html and with Intel vs PowerPC :-)